# How to convert websites into Kindle documents?

Tags: epub, kindle, mobi

I want to convert a set of websites into a Kindle document.

So far I have managed to convert the web sites into `epub` via ECub and from there into `Mobi` via Calibre, but unfortunately I am losing all pictures.

Could you recommend any other tool for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://klip.me/sendtokindle/ may be useful.

> "Send to Kindle" is a Browser extension for Kindle owners who prefer
>   reading web content on their devices. It’s designed to offer a quick
>   way for pushing web content to Kindle, then you can read the articles
>   or news later on your device.

Works on Safari, Chrome, Firefox and IE. There is even a bookmarklet version.

Comment: http://sendtoreader.com/ is another service which works much like klip.me

Comment: Yet another free one: http://www.readability.com

Answer (score 4):

[Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com) has a service that will send a weekly email to your Kindle containing a set of webpages that you've picked, formatted for reading on a Kindle in a "magazine style" with each web page working like a magazine article (meaning you can skip from web page to web page).

Just register on the Instapaper site, give them your Kindle's email address, and add their email to your Kindle's email white-list (on the Kindle settings page on Amazon). Now put the ["ReadLater" bookmarklet](http://www.instapaper.com/extras) on your browser's toolbar, and just click it whenever you're on an interesting page that you'd rather read later on your Kindle.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Mac, you can consider what I did with an application called DeepVacuum.

A relative took a cross-country bike trip and posted his daily updates online with pictures.  Once the trip was over, I was able to download his 45 day diary with this software.  It saved the content as a PDF which you can copy from your computer to a Kindle.

I have not read his diary on a Kindle but I printed out the hard copy.  It rendered nicely on 8.5 X 11 paper which he keeps in case the website ever decides to take down his diary.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the site to .pdf then convert the .pdf for easy viewing and email it to your Kindle...
http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/, http://www.willus.com/k2pdfopt/

Answer (score 0):

There is an official Amazon extension for Firefox and Chrome, and various other methods available on their website here:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_bc_nav?ie=UTF8&nodeId=201238330

You can also find it on the http://addons.mozilla.org site for Firefox (or via the "Add-ons" menu item in Firefox), called "Send To Kindle".

This gets you to log in on the amazon site and then works nicely  :)
(Just tested this with Firefox 32 and it worked really well, reformatted the page into a good readable format)